# Convert probability outputs to binary in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose that we have this matrix in MATLAB R2015a:

```
a = [0.97 0.03
0.6 0.4
0.3 0.7];
```

I want convert it to:

```
a1 = [1 0
1 0
0 1]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

By using round(), it rounds everything to the nearest integer, exactly what you are doing here.

```
a1 = round(a)
```

[MATLAB's round() documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html)

Comment: Nicely done (+1). However, it fails if a row contains `0.5` twice. On the other hand, the OP hasn't defined the desired behaviour in that case

Comment: @LuisMendo Could you elaborate on that? `round([0.5 0.5; 0.5 0.5])`rounds to 1 for me.

Comment: @kkuilla I'm assuming the OP wants the _sum of each row to equal 1_. Admittedly the question is unclear

Comment: @LuisMendo I don't understand what you mean. The aggregate of each row seem to be 1 imho but I agree. The question is unclear.

Comment: @LuisMendo Ok, got your point now. The OP needs to add some clarifications. Anyway, having 2 equal probabilities (0.5) in a row and having integers seems a bit incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

```
>> a = [0.97 0.03
0.6 0.4
0.3 0.7];

>> a > 0.5

ans =

     1     0
     1     0
     0     1
```